# connect mongoDB atlas to angular

Tags: angular, typescript, mongodb-atlas

My code written by typescript language in angular.
I am building a project that must use cloudDB.

I have a user cluster in mongodb atlas and I copied the string for `node.js` to connect as an application but I don't know where to write my mongoDB code in angular.

I see a lot of openSource but sometimes it damages my project then I had to fix it, or the opensource code only works with `.js` files.

How can I make my project export parameters to my DB cluster.

All of my files are Typescript (`.ts`) format.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a backend server that communicates with mongodb.
This is because it's to unsecure to allow your angular app to talk directly to mongodb.

I would suggest to use the combination of

nest.js to write your api https://nestjs.com/
and use NX to have both your angular app and api in the same repo.
https://nx.dev

nest looks a lot like angular, but is only for the server side.
and nx is great for structuring your app and api and they have a lot of code examples and best practices regarding how to write your code.

I've been using this setup for the last ~2 years and I'm very happy with it.

Comment: Thank you Leon, you offer to me kind of server but this is cannot allow to me to connect to mongodb atlas in specific. do you know how to connect?, mybe such a opensource Code with angular typescript architecture.

Comment: You will need to have a backend server. there is no way to connect directly from angular to mongodb. the node.js mongodb api is really god so use that in your nest.js app https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb to connect to mongodb atlas

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it would make sense to take a step back and take a look at how a simple architecture diagram of a standard application deployed on AWS VPC looks like:

The client fetches the website resource hosted in the public subnet inside the AWS VPC and see it in its chrome browser, which means the angular code are fetched and use on client side unlike server side technologies with PHP etc.
Every time the angular needs remote data to be displayed on the browser, it will communicate with the proxy.
The proxy will check regarding authentication, certificates and route through to the backend if the check is ok.

Backend does not have the data, but will query them from a database.
Backend and database are all hosted in a private subnet out of security reasons, because offering direct access from the internet to your backend or database is never a good idea for production applications.
And client side frameworks like angular are not designed to fetch data directly from databases, because I think you have already seen this:
Job description for `full-stack`,`backend` only and `frontend` only positions :)

```
     +------------------------------------------------+
     |                 UserAgent (Web Browser)        |
     +------------+------------------------^----------+
                  |                        |
 Route 53         |                        |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
s p               |                        |
u u   +-----------v----------+ +-----------+----------+
b b   |         Proxy        | |        Frontend      |
n l   +-----------+----------+ +----------------------+
e i               |
t c               |                         Api Gateway
+-----------------------------------------------------+
s p               |
u r   +-----------v----------+
b i   |        Backend       |
n v   +----------------------+
e i               |
t t               |
  e   +-----------v----------+
      |       Database       |
      +-----------+----------+
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

## Frontend:

- server side: PHP etc.
- client side js: `angular`, `react`, `vue` etc.

## Backend:

- `Node`, `Java` (Spring Boot), `Python` (Django), `Ruby`(Rails), `PHP`
- It is nice to know that for performance irrelevant apps, you can use an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping) framework so that you keep SQL queries out of your backend code, e.g. [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) for node, [mongoRepository with spring data](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/) for Spring Boot.
  And with [liquibase](https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app), [mongock](https://www.mongock.io/quick-start) you can do database migration with your SQL or nosql databases

## Database

- SQL: MySQL, Postgres
- noSql: mongo
- Graph: neo4j

You can also do serverless computing with lambda and firebase, it is always possible, but I think let's do not jump too far this time ;)

Comment: Thank you Yuqiu, you offer to me kind of explanation of database --> frontEnd  architecture but this is cannot allow to me to connect to mongodb atlas in specific. do you know how to connect?, mybe such a opensource Code with angular typescript architecture.